# Run an Update with three case expressions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update 3 fields in a table, based on 3 case expressions.  Here is my non-working code.

```
UPDATE MyPrices
  SET ID_ISIN = ID_ISIN
  SET ID_SEDOL = ID_SEDOL
  SET ID_CUSIP = ID_CUSIP
  MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'ISN' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END) As ID_ISIN,
  MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'SED' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END) As ID_SEDOL,
  MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'CSP' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END) As ID_CUSIP
FROM CPDG As CPDG
    INNER JOIN CW As CW
    ON CPDG.asset_id = CW.asset_id
GROUP BY CW.asset_id;
```

I tried a couple different versions of this, and I keep getting errors saying

> Incorrect syntax near 'SET'.

If I get rid of the UPDATE and do a SELECT, I get this.

```
ID_ISIN   ID_SEDOL   ID_CUSIP
NULL      2450915    448814DM2
```

I'm trying to grab these 3 items and push them into a different table, which summarizes things based on this relationship: `CPDG.asset_id = CW.asset_id`

The data that I'm working with comes in really crappy, otherwise I wouldn't have to do this step.

Comment: You dont have to say "SET" multiple times for multiple fields, Just separate them with Comma. SET ID_ISIN= ID_ISIN, ID_SEDOL=ID_SEDOL, ID_CUSIP= ... .

Comment: Your whole query is wrong

Comment: I don't even see what kind of relationship is supposed to be between MyPrices and CPDG + CW. Why don't you explain what you were trying to achieve ?. A few examples would also be helpful.

Comment: Instead of having us backwards engineer your very wrong sql, can you please share some sample data for these tables and your desired results after this runs (with explanation of any logic you are wanting to implement to get to the desired results, if it's not obvious). Then we can help construct a working UPDATE statement.

Comment: Also, you can't use aggregation in an update statement.

Comment: start with writing a select statement that returns the values you want to update. Then convert to an update statement.

Comment: `set id_isin = coalesce((select max(id_number) from cw where cw.asset_id = MyPrices.asset_id and id_cd = 'ISN'), id_isin), ...`

Comment: Not sure about the relationship between MyPrices and CPDG. Subqueries are really the standard way to do this.

Comment: Please study about update statement before you write one. There are too many errors here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really reconsider what you're trying to achieve, as there are many errors in this query.  I'm not sure why you're trying to set each column twice (among other errors), and you haven't given us what you're expecting.  However, I'll answer with the following attempt to understand and clean up your code (***Disclaimer:*** this is untested):

```
UPDATE MyPrices
    SET ID_ISIN = MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'ISN' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END),
    ID_SEDOL = MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'SED' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END),
    ID_CUSIP = MAX(CASE WHEN CW.id_cd = 'CSP' THEN CW.id_number ELSE NULL END)
FROM CPDG As CPDG
    INNER JOIN CW As CW
    ON CPDG.asset_id = CW.asset_id;
```

I'd also advise running against test data (maybe via temp tables or something?), as this answer is based off very limited info.  I'd also look into everyone else's comments on your initial post, as they all made great suggestions.

Comment: As I wrote in the comment to the question: You can't use aggregation in an update statement.

Comment: Yep, I missed that in my copy-over the code too.   Good catch.

Comment: This kind of proves rethinking his query though.   Maybe needs to do it with a subquery or something.